# iCloud & Core Data gremlins in iOS9 implementation

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, icloud

Is there any reliable documentation on iCloud and Core Data implementation which works reliably in iOS9?

I've setup storeURL XXX.sqlite and modelURL momd, hooked it into managedObjectContext & PersistentStack, upgraded iCloud and enabled/set default container in XCode Capabilities.

When I have internet connectivity on the device, the app works fine. As soon as I disable wifi the gremlins come out. Especially after I restart the app (still with wifi off) only to find partial data (some elements missing) and some elements showing up as null. Very strange behavior.

Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction or shed some light on what I am seeing. Happy to provide code samples if it helps?